# Constructor parameters with same name as atributes

Tags: scala

In Java, I can do this:

```
class Point{
  int x, y;
  public Point (int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }
}
```

How can I do the same thing in Scala (use the same names in constructor arguments and in class attributes):

```
class Point(x: Int, y: Int){
  //Wrong code
  def x = x;
  def y = y;
}
```

---

**Edit**

I'm asking this because the code below doesn't work

```
class Point(x: Int, y: Int) {
    def +(that: Point): Point = new Point(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y)
}
```

But the following one works:

```
class Point(px: Int, py: Int) {
  def x = px
  def y = py
  def +(that: Point): Point = new Point(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y)
}
```

Comment: In the first code fragment in your edit, use `val` to declare the arguments, and your code works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Scala the parameters of the constructor become public attributes of the class if declared as a `var` or `val`.

```
scala> class Point(val x: Int, val y: Int){}
defined class Point

scala> val point = new Point(1,1)
point: Point = Point@1bd53074

scala> point.x
res0: Int = 1

scala> point.y
res1: Int = 1
```

**Edit to answer the question in comments** "if they were private fields, shouldn't my first code snipped after the edit have worked?"

The constructor `class Point(x: Int, y: Int)` generates *object-private* fields which only allow methods of the `Point` class to access the fields `x` and `y` not other objects of type `Point`. `that` in the `+` method is another object and is not allowed access with this definition. To see this in action define add a method `def xy:Int = x + y` which does not generate a compile error.

To have `x` and `y` accessible to the class use a *class-private* field which is as follows:

```
class Point(private val x: Int, private val y: Int) {
    def +(that: Point): Point = new Point(this.x + that.x, this.y + that.y)
}
```

Now they are not accessible outside of the class:

```
scala> val point = new Point(1,1)
point: Point = Point@43ba9cea

scala> point.x
<console>:10: error: value x in class Point cannot be accessed in Point
              point.x
                    ^
scala> point.y
<console>:10: error: value y in class Point cannot be accessed in Point
              point.y
```

You can see this in action by using `scalac -Xprint:parser Point.scala`.

Comment: Oh, thanks! If i don't set them to val, they are just parameters to the constructor then, is that it? What if I wanted them to be private attributes?

Comment: See http://www.scala-lang.org/node/539#comment-650 for how to make the arguments private.

Comment: If you don't add `var` or `val` they are parameters to the constructor and private fields in the class. Also see the section "Constructors in Scala" in the book http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/BasicObjectOrientedProgramming.html

Comment: Gonna take a look, thank =). But anyway, if they were private fields, shouldn't my first code snipped after the  edit have worked?

Comment: They behave as if they where annotated with private[this], i.e. they are only visible in the current instance.

Comment: @Brian - The fields aren't created at all unless there's a declaration that needs to close over one of them. E.g., if he changes `def x = px` to `val x = px` in his last example then no field is created for `px` (verified with a quick run of _javap_).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to; the "arguments" in the class declarations are all you need in Scala.

Comment: Ah, see Brian's answer.  Use `val`.